# Database class object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've seen people use this piece of code and I'm trying to understand what it does because I don't see it in any of the codeigniter documenation or in the source code for the database class.

```
$this->db->ar_orderby
```

Comment: Adding some context would certainly help

Comment: From what my noobnes tells me, `$this` is a special variable meant to refere a class  and the `->` means sort of get/use in this case, I would presume `db` is actually a variable to hold database resource and as a variable was declared as `$db` but if you are using `$this->` you can't use the `$` sign... I started learning OOP just about yesterday, and that is all that I know :)

Comment: db is probably instantiated in the constructor. $this->db would get you that db instance within any functions in that class.

Comment: After some searching, I'm fairly convinced that ar_orderby() is a deprecated function. You should use $this->db->order_by();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an array that holds order by columns..

**There should be no reason to use this property directly.  Instead call `$this->db->order_by('column')` which appends to the array automatically.**

- defined in `system/database/DB_active_rec.php` Line 42
- appended to in method `CI_DB_active_record::order_by` Line 856
- used to generate SQL in `CI_DB_active_record::_compile_select` Line 1781

Answer (score 3):

You mean

http://phpxref.com/xref/codeigniter/system/drivers/DB_active_record.php.source.html#l781

It allows you to specify the order by.

Answer (score 3):

It still makes sense to use this in the way below -

```
if (!count($this->db->ar_orderby)) {
    $this->db->order_by($this->order_by );
}
```

It basically means - If an order is not already set by db library when this method was called, use this. Prevents calling of "order by" twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace these lines:

```
if (!count($this->db->ar_orderby)) {
    $this->db->order_by($this->order_by );
}
```

with:

```
if(!count($this->db->order_by($this->order_by))) {
    $this->db->order_by($this->order_by);
}
```